# Is there open source software for SEM EDX data analysis?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, software, elements, x-ray-diffraction

This can't be unique to me and would apply to anybody who has to use equipment in other departments has had departments move etc.

*What open source packages exist to read and potentially manipulate SEM EDX (electron dispersive x-ray elemental analysis) data after the data has been collected?*

(In my case I have data from an Oxford Instruments EDX but there are many more manufacturers.)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [HyperSpy library](http://hyperspy.org) for Python.

Some examples of what you can do with it are available [here](http://hyperspy.org/hyperspy-doc/current/user_guide/eds.html).

Comment: brr, Python - but its something :) - thanks - I wonder what the others will suggest? (+1)

Comment: Hehe :) I guess you have tried with Originlab,  the free version is pretty useful.

Comment: @davcs86 did hyperspy work for you? as i work mainly on TEM-EDS platform and it gives out ipj format, and there is nothing that i could find to analyse data other than the bundled software. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hyperspy-users/YbM5F7cN950
here it is mentioned that hyperspy works on opensource data format which is supported by bruker but not oxford :(